# WordPress & Woocommerce Product Image for Each Attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

Here is what I would like to do. Say, for example I have 3 attributes (Type, Color & Design). Typically the main product image would change as you selected each of the attributes if you have a picture in the variation. Instead of the image changing I would like to display an additional image for each attribute. So in this case, once you selected all 3 attributes you would see 3 different images.

I am just getting started on this project and looking for some direction on how to accomplish this. I couldnt find an extension that did this and google wasnt helping!

Note: I have a license for ACF Pro, not sure if that will be needed though

Comment: well, if i undertand you, with ACF you can add those custom img fields into the product edit page, and then on the front-end show or not those imgs clicking some nav made of those attributes. That´s not hard to do.

Comment: Yeah, I can do all that pretty easy but I don't know that's the best way to go about it.  If I went with that approach, those custom fields wouldn't be tied to Woocommerce in anyway.  For example, someone could add a product to their cart without selecting one, and if they did select one I would have to figure out how to pass that info along throughout the checkout process

Comment: And what about using this way: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-project-meta-field/